# checkbox for dropdownlist

Tags: drop-down-menu, checkbox, for-loop

I am binding `drodownlist` from Db as shown below:

```
ddlTemplates.DataSource = ObjBlTemplate.DsGetTemplate;

ddlTemplates.DataTextField = "templateTitle";

ddlTemplates.DataValueField = "templateID";

ddlTemplates.DataBind();
```

I need to display checkbox for each and every field.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net you have not any built in function to do this.If you want to use `javascript` with your asp.net code [link](http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=63)  here is a example about this.